# select multiple options sql and php

Tags: php, html, sql

I'm working on a small project at work. The intention is to receive data from my MS SQL Express server 2008 to a webpage. This is all working fine. I use the ODBC connect extension to do this. I have set a callender, so you can pick date's between you want to receive. But like i said, this is all working fine.

**My problem:** 
I want to get data from diffrent SQL servers. 3 in total. My sql statement is on every sql server the same. The only thing that need to change is the connection string and the database. Here you will find my PHP Code. I will use the $_POST in php ro receive the action from my form.

In HTML you can see that i use a select option. Whenever i choose for 'Grimbergen' the connection string must change to $connection_string = $grim; And when I choose for 'Gent' the connection string must change

```
$connection_string = $topo;

if (isset($_POST['knop'])) {
    $user = 'someuser'; 
    $pass = 'somepassword';
    $grim = 'DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=10.10.10.10\UNIWIN_GRIM;DATABASE=UniCla';
    $topo = 'DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=10.10.10.10\UNIWIN_TOPO;DATABASE=UniCla';
    $connection_string = ;  //don't know how i get this with $_POST!!!
    echo $connection_string;
    $connection = odbc_connect( $connection_string, $user, $pass ); 

    if (odbc_error()) {
        echo odbc_errormsg($connection);
    }
    $connection = odbc_connect( $connection_string, $user, $pass ); 

    // you must set the connection first
    if (odbc_error()) {
        echo odbc_errormsg($connection);
    }

    $bdate= $_POST['bdate'];
    $edate= $_POST['edate'];
    $grim_s = 'SRGR';
    $topo_s = 'SRTO';
    $stmt = "SELECT String1, String3, String13, String15, String4, String8, InOut, Weight1, Date1, Time1, Weight2, Date2, Time2, Nett FROM dbo.Move WHERE Date1 BETWEEN '$bdate' AND '$edate' AND String13='$grim_s' ORDER BY Date1 desc;";
    $result = odbc_exec($connection, $stmt);
```

**And the HTML:**

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" name="formulier" id="formulier" action="">
    <div>
        <h4>Site</h4>
        <p>
            <select name="place" id="place" class="form-control" >
                <option value="grim">Grimbergen</option>
                <option value="gent">Gent</option>
            </select>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <h4>Begin Date</h4>
        <input name="bdate" id="picker1" class="form-control" type="text">
    </div>
    <div>
        <h4>End Date</h4>
        <input name="edate" id="picker2" class="form-control" type="text">
    </div>
    <br>
    <div>
        <button type="submit" value="login" class="btn btn-info btn-fill pull-right" name="knop" id="knop">Submit</button>
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: You meant get the data from different database, bur same query ?

Comment: Yes. The query is the same.

Comment: okay Is that grim and gent are database or tell your database name

Comment: When you select Grimbergen in HTML the connection string must change to 'DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=10.10.10.10\UNIWIN_GRIM;DATABASE=UniCla'. When you select Gent in HTML the connection string must be 'DRIVER={SQL Server};SERVER=10.10.10.10\UNIWIN_TOPO;DATABASE=UniCla'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fine Use select value as your DB Name like this

```
        <select name="place" id="place" class="form-control" >
            <option value="GRIM">Grimbergen</option>
            <option value="TOPO">Gent</option>
        </select>
```

And when you post use one connection string like this

```
$connection_string ='DRIVER={SQL server};SERVER=10.10.10.10\UNIWIN_'.$_POST['place'].';DATABASE=UniCla';
```

Comment: Sorry, i didn't mension this. The IP address is also different. For Grimbergen it is 10.10.10.10, and for Gent 10.10.11.10. Is this also possible?

Comment: Thats fine use simple IF condition. if($_POST['place'] == 'GRIM'){ $ip="10.10.10.10";}else{$ip="10.10.11.10";}   $connection_string ='DRIVER={SQL server};SERVER='.$ip.'\UNIWIN_'.$_POST['place'].';DATABASE=UniCla';

Comment: Thank you. This has helped me!